# Declaring variable inside function not updating outside swift

Tags: swift, function, methods, global-variables

I have a function where it goes into firebase data base and pulls the amount of items I have stored. It returns three when I print the variable postCount in the function itself but when I print it anywhere else it only has zero. It doesn't seem to be updating the global value.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {
    var items: [Int] = []
    var postCount = 0
    @IBOutlet var carousel: iCarousel!

    func getData() {
        Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict2 = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.postCount = dict2.count
            }

            //This prints 3
            print(self.postCount)
        })
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print(self.postCount)
        for i in 0 ... 99 {
            items.append(i)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()
        print(self.postCount)
        carousel.type = .cylinder
    }

    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return postCount
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var label: UILabel
        var itemView: UIImageView

        //reuse view if available, otherwise create a new view
        if let view = view as? UIImageView {
            itemView = view
            //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
            label = itemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        } else {
            //don't do anything specific to the index within
            //this `if ... else` statement because the view will be
            //recycled and used with other index values later
            itemView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 400))
            itemView.image = UIImage(named: "page.png")
            itemView.layer.borderWidth = 10
            itemView.contentMode = .center

            label = UILabel(frame: itemView.bounds)
            label.backgroundColor = .clear
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = label.font.withSize(50)
            label.tag = 1
            itemView.addSubview(label)
        }

        //set item label
        //remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
        //views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
        //you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
        //in the wrong place in the carousel
        label.text = "\(items[index])"

        return itemView
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if (option == .spacing) {
            return value * 1.1
        }
        return value
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the 'awakeFromNib' isn't being called before 'viewDidLoad'?, I'm not positive but it might come as part of the super.viewDidLoad(). Try moving super.viewDidLoad() to the bottom of viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because retrieving data from Firebase is asynchronous. `getData()` is called and then instantly after that you `print(self.postCount)`, even though `getData()` is still retrieving the data from Firebase.

Try changing the `print(self.postCount)` within `getData()` to

`print("Data Loaded and there are \(self.postCount) posts")`

and you should see in your log that the `print(self.postCount)` within viewDidLoad() is called before the `print` within `getData()`. As a result, when `print(self.postCount)` in viewDidLoad() is called, `postCount` still equals the default value of 0 since `getValue()` has not completed running even though that `print` is on the line after `getData()`.

You probably want to call whatever functions that need to use the updated `postCount` inside the closure in `getData()` so that you ensure those functions use the updated `postCount`.

For example:

```
func getData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dict2 = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.postCount = dict2.count
        }

        print(self.postCount)

        //everything within this closure will have the updated value of postCount
        foo()
    })
}

func foo() {
    if self.postCount > 0 {
        print("Lots of posts!")
    }
    else {
        print("No posts :(")
    }
}
```